# Go gota Dataframe not loading struct, requires []struct

Tags: go, struct, gota

I am reading a file with each row containing two words separated by a space. I scan and split each line to two words (strings) and store them in the `MyEntity` struct (in `items`). The words are then added to `items`.

```
type Entity struct {
    Name string
    Entity string 
}

type MyEntity struct {
    Entities []Entity
}

func (entity *MyEntity) AddEntity(item Entity) []Entity {
    entity.Entities = append(entity.Entities, item)
    return entity.Entities
}

...

items := MyEntity{}

// loop here over the rows - name is first word, entity is second word

item := Entity{
    name, entity,
}

items.AddEntity(item)

...
```

Should `items` not be a `[]struct` here? I am using the `gota` package (https://github.com/go-gota/gota) to create a DataFrame from `items` but using `dataframe.LoadStructs(items)` fails because `items` is a `struct` and it must be a `[]struct`.

I am fairly new to Go, so what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the data frame from the slice of entities:

```
 df := dataframe.LoadStructs(items.Entities)
```

Comment: That did it, completely missed that. Cheers.